# How can I get return data when using command line commands?

Tags: c++, command-line, shellexecuteex

I inherited a c++ application that runs some commands using 'ShellExecuteEx', specifically using appcmd.exe. I would like to be able to run the command and then get the return data as I would see it if I ran it from the commandline.

I don't necessarily want to use ShellExecuteEx, but if I don't use that I need to run something pretty simple, as I am not used to c++ programming. My background is more of C# and similar languages.

Comment: So you want to gather data the executed program sent to its `stdout` and reap it for your own nefarious purposes. Is that about right? If so, I sincerely wish you the best of luck in [deciphering this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). And pay close attention to the comments. There are *plenty* that are relevant.

Comment: Yes? I don't want to stop it from doing that, I just want to see what it is? Is this like a huge security hole? If so, what are my alternatives?